# Sorting data in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Working in powershell I am wondering how to Sort a txt file formated like

```text
Smith,John,45
Jean,Rob,60
```

The code I have listed below sorts the Last names correctly but I cannot get the average age of all the names and also when I try to get the Age sorted output it only displays some of the names. Any suggestions on how to properly get these outputs?

```sh
#Average age of Data   
$fileLines = Get-Content -Path C:\PowerShell\m22.txt   
-split '\r?\n'

$fileLines | Measure-Object { [int] $_.age } -Average | ForEach-Object Average

#Last name sorted Output  
Get-Content -Path C:\PowerShell\m22.txt | Sort-Object

#Age sorted Output  
$fileLines = Get-Content -Path C:\PowerShell\m22.txt  
-split '\r?\n'

$fileLines | Sort-Object -Descending { [int] ($_ -split ',')[-1] }
```

Comment: So you want to sort by name, or age? Then get the age average??

Comment: This question isn't fundamentally different from your earlier one. If you have a follow-up question to it, please build on the solutions you were given there. The code you're showing here doesn't work, and suggests conceptual confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The data is already comma seperated, making it ideal to use [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.2) like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\m22.txt' -Delimiter ',' -Header Lastname,Firstname,Age
```

Note that if your file already has a line with header names you can omit the `-Header` parameter.

To sort the list:

```
# sort
$csv = $csv | Sort-Object LastName
```

And to get average age:

```
# get average age
$csv | Measure-Object -Property Age -Average
```

Comment: Using `Import-Csv` is a good idea, and even though the properties of the objects that the CSV rows are parsed into are invariably _strings_. Luckily, [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) implicitly converts such strings to numbers.

Comment: thanks this really helps, this is my first time in powershell when i have all these in a program and run it are they all suppose to output?

Comment: @Tiberious, the level of guidance you're looking for is beyond the mandate of this site. I recommend reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You've been given sufficient input to solve your problem, both in the linked duplicate and here. Perhaps a colleague or a different, more conversational forum can provide the step-by-step guidance you seem to be looking for. You're always welcome to post focused, well-defined questions of general interest here.